# Required Transition found: MaterialContainerTransform?

Tags: android, android-activity, material-design, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

In my activity, I'm trying to use MaterialContainerTransform but it shows an error that

*Required **Transition** found: **MaterialContainerTransform***

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
    setEnterSharedElementCallback(MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback())
    //this is giving error
    window.sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
        addTarget(android.R.id.content)
        duration = 300L
    }
    window.sharedElementReturnTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
        addTarget(android.R.id.content)
        duration = 250L
    }
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
//material
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'

def coroutines_version = "1.3.8"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
```

}

Comment: This is the reference key from where I was trying to do this, It's official Material.io website  [Material Transitions](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two types of `MaterialContainerTransform` the [`com.google.android.material.transition.MaterialContainerTransform`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/transition/MaterialContainerTransform)  that uses AndroidX Transition and includes bug fixes that apply to all API levels and the [com.google.android.material.transition.**platform**.MaterialContainerTransform](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/transition/platform/MaterialContainerTransform) class that is built on the framework Transition class.

Only the framework Transition version can be used for window transitions, so you should make sure you're importing the right version of `MaterialContainerTransform`:

```
import com.google.android.material.transition.platform.MaterialContainerTransform
```